# When I try to update my database with PGSQL on Heroku, I get a 22001 error

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, heroku, knex.js

I am working on a project that uses KnexJS with PGSQL on Heroku. My issue is that when I update the signature_url field (text), I receive a PGSQL 22001 error (details listed below). The thing that is being updated into the signature_url field is a string created by the .toDataUrl() JavaScript method. This method returns a string that is 16,158 characters long. This all seems to work fine when using SQLite3 in development but breaks when I try to update via PGSQL on Heroku.

Here are my migrations:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('contracts', function (table) {
    table.increments('id')
    table.integer('owner_id')
    table.integer('signee_id')
    table.string('contract_header')
    table.text('contract_desc')
    table.text('signature_url')
    table.string('date_signed')
    table.boolean('isSigned')
  })
  };

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('contracts')
};
```

Here are my original seeds:

```
exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('contracts').del()
    .then(function () {
      // Inserts seed entries
      return knex('contracts').insert([
        {owner_id: 1, signee_id: 2, contract_header: 'Rugby Coaching Position', contract_desc: 'Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada.', signature_url: '', date_signed: '', isSigned: false},
        {owner_id: 1, signee_id: 2, contract_header: 'Arts Perfomance', contract_desc: 'Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada.', signature_url: '', date_signed: '', isSigned: false},
        {owner_id: 2, signee_id: 1, contract_header: 'Field Trip', contract_desc: 'Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada.', signature_url: '', date_signed: '', isSigned: false}
      ]);
    });
};
```

This is the object that is returned when checking the network on Dev Tools.

```
code:"22001"
file:"varchar.c"
length:99
line:"624"
name:"error"
routine:"varchar"
severity:"ERROR"
```

db.js

```
function signContract (id, signatureUrl) {
  return knex('contracts').where('id', id)
  .update({ signature_url: signatureUrl })
}
```

knexfile.js

```
module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
      filename: './dev.sqlite3'
    }
  },

  staging: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'my_db',
      user:     'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  test: {
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {
    filename: './dev.sqlite3'
  }
},

  production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: Can you provide your knex config that you pass to knex constructor?

Comment: @coockoo Have just added my knex config above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert data into a `varchar` column, but the length of the string exceeds the length of the column.

You can either insert a shorter string or use `ALTER TABLE` to increase the length of the `varchar` column.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your types for your columns. Because your error states that you are trying to put big value inside small type. Check your table definition in `psql` interface with `\d table_name`.

If you see non-`text` columns – try to replace them with

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ALTER COLUMN col_name TYPE text;
```

I prefer using [text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html) fields

**UPD:** And try to check your `NODE_ENV` variable inside of your application. Maybe you are connected to `sqlite` database. I tried to reproduce your situation on my local postgres and everything works just fine.

**PS** And why don't you use postgres for development/test environments? For example, you'll need some `postgres`-only features in your app, so that means you cannot test your app in development. But this goes beyond this question.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers for your help people! I've taken your ideas and applied it to KnexJS by modifying my `table.string("signature_url")` column by declaring a value for the maximum character length `table.string("signature_url", 17000)`. This seems to of worked!